# awk: Create new record and update NR

Tags: awk

More of a general question rather than a specific problem to solve.

Say I have a file like

```
entry 1
entry 3
entry 6
```

And I want to fill in the missing entries via `awk`. Could one insert a new record and update NR? Idea is:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "NR","line"
     $2!=NR {<create record> "entry",NR ; <repeat commands on same record>}
     {print NR,$0}' file
```

So the command would:

- insert a new record
- give the new record the matching NR and update the following record numbers
- have the ability to recheck the condition (i.e.: when `entry 6` is reached, it should create `entry 4` but realize that `entry 5` is missing, too. So it should recheck the condition for the `entry 6` record)

Desired output

```
NR line
1  entry 1
2  entry 2
3  entry 3
4  entry 4
5  entry 5
6  entry 6
```

Comment: Are you sure you talk about total number of records `NR`? Or you mean number of current record `FNR`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Well, it should act on both.

Comment: @Archemar AFAIK input is read record-by-record and each on is given an NR (and FNR). The question is if one can a) insert a record before the current one, b) give it matching NR/FNR (and update the following record reads with new NR/FNR), and c) rerun a command on the current record (like the opposite of `next` statement)

Comment: A similar idea is: `if ($2 > NR) for(i=NR; i < $2; i++) print "entry "i; else print $0;` but without the NR prefix. Feel free to use this as a starting point for any answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** create a new input record in one pass of an input file. Creating a new input record would mean that this code:

```
awk '
    {
        print $0
        magic to create a new record with contents "Foo"
    }
'
```

would print the original record then enter an infinite loop printing "Foo" because by definition awk executes the above code once per input record.

You can do things to execute code on strings whether they're from an input record or created internally, e.g.:

```
awk '
    {
        prt($0)
        other stuff
        prt("Foo")
    }
    function prt(str) {
        print str
    }
'
```

but that's not the same as actually creating a new input record.

You could also do a 2-pass approach to create and write to a temp file on the first pass so that when reading the temp file for the second pass the newly printed strings are now present as input records.

You're overload/abusing the meaning of `NR` though. `NR` is the count of **input** records read, you're trying to print a count of **output** records printed which is a completely different thing. There is no builtin variable for that as it's trivial to just keep track of it yourself in a separate variable rather than messing with `NR`, e.g. with `onr` below:

```
$ cat file
awk '
    BEGIN { print "NR", "onr", "line" }
    NR == 1 { val = $2-1 }
    {
        for (val++; val<$2; val++) {
            processString($1 FS val)
        }
        processString($0)
    }

    function processString(str) {
        print NR, ++onr, str
    }
' file
NR onr line
1 1 entry 13
2 2 entry 14
2 3 entry 15
3 4 entry 16
3 5 entry 17
3 6 entry 18
```

Again though - we are NOT creating new input records and so (**as always**) it'd be completely inappropriate to try to adjust the value of the builtin variable `NR`. Instead we're simply generating new output records and keeping track of the total number of output records in a user-defined variable named `onr`.

I added both `NR` and `onr` to the output and changed the sample input to:

```
$ cat file
entry 13
entry 15
entry 18
```

to highlight that there's actually 3 separate data items in play:

1. `NR` = the number of input records,
2. `onr` = the number of output records,
3. `val` = the value of the $2 to be printed for each record

and for clarity, cohesion, coupling, maintenance etc. of your program it's best not to overload any of them.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. And in the same manner one could take track of an analogous `ofnr` like `FNR<oldFNR { ofnr=0 } { <for-loop> ; <string-function> ; ofnr++ ; oldFNR=FNR}`

Comment: `FNR==1{ofnr=0} ... function processString(str) { print NR, ++onr, ++ofnr, str }`

Comment: The question is though - what do you want `ofnr` to mean? Is it the count of records output from   the current input file or the count of records output to the current output file. Again, they're potentially 2 different things. Whatever they are they should be incremented inside `processString(str)` as that's where you write the output from, but the one gets initialized when the input file changes (as I show in my comment) and the other when the output file changes.

Comment: In that case, I understood it as "count of output records with respect to beginning of current input file". Of course on could also differentiate here in case of several output files. But no matter how - the general idea of doing the counting on your own and not touching (F)NR remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT + Warning**

As stated in the comments below, `NR` and `FNR` are *by definition* counters for **input records** and should therefore stay untouched. (Ref: [gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Records)) Do not manipulate there values as suggested below despite the ability to do so without restriction! I'll leave this answer as a warning.

---

Okay, thanks to the comments of Jeff Schaller, Romeo Ninov and fra-san, the following approaches work:

- manually increasing `NR` or `FNR`
- use a properly defined loop with `NR` / `FNR`

Possible script:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "NR","line"}
     $2 > NR { for (NR; NR<$2; NR++) print NR,"entry "NR }
     {print NR,$0}' infile
```

Replace `NR` by `FNR` to ensure proper numbering in case of multiple input files (and maybe still use `NR++` to ensure the correct total number).

Hereby `NR++` simulates updating `NR`, while the loop simulates rerunning commands on the same record (pseudo-opposite of the `next` statement) which in total makes it like a newly created record with matching `NR` (`FNR`).

Comment: Asides: a way to make this work for `$2` <= 0 would be to set the initial `NR` in a `BEGIN {getline; NR=$2; print NR,$0}` block; also, it may be useful to make sure `$2` is correctly parsed as a number, e.g. with `$2 = ($2 + 0)` (possibly in place of the `$2 > NR` condition, which seems redundant).

Comment: The effect of incrementing `NR` is undefined, I wouldn't rely on incrementing it doing what you want. You're also overloading it's meaning - `NR` is the count of **input** records read, you're trying to print a count of **output** records printed which is a completely different thing and there is no builtin variable for but it's trivial to just keep track of it yourself in a separate variable rather than messing with `NR`.

Comment: @EdMorton It makes sense to strictly interpret `NR` and `FNR` as input counters. I used to understand them as record counters in general. But your interpretation makes more sense.

Comment: Yeah, [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) isn't as clear as it could be on the fact FNR and NR are about **input** records (`FNR The ordinal number of the current record in the current file` and `NR The ordinal number of the current record from the start of input.`) but [the gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) states it clearly: `FNR indicates how many records have been read from the current input file; NR indicates how many records have been read in total.`